# Java - adding existing objects to view iterating through an array list

Tags: java, android, eclipse, arraylist, iteration

what I want to do is press a button to add previously declared TableRow objects (refers to TableRow objects already created in XML file) that I have hidden using table.removeView(row1) etc on program start.

Then I want to be able to click a button to add each TableRow back to the view one at a time until all the rows are visible again. I have tried a few different ways without any luck and the last method I tried was creating an array list in my onCreate method like so:

```
final ArrayList<TableRow> rowlist = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
rowlist.add(row4);
rowlist.add(row5);
rowlist.add(row6);
rowlist.add(row7);
rowlist.add(row8);
rowlist.add(row9);
rowlist.add(row10);
```

Then trying to iterate through like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Iterator<TableRow> rowiterator = rowlist.iterator();
while (rowiterator.hasNext()) {
table.addView(rowiterator.next());
}
}
```

What I get now is when I press my button it just adds all the rows back in at once, when I want it to iterate through the list adding rows one at a time.

Can anyone help me resolve this problem, or tell me if I'm being a complete idiot and suggest an entirely new and better method of achieving what I want to achieve?

Note: I'm pretty new to Java programming and on this problem I am absolutely stumped!

Comment: Instead of doing the whole list, how about just adding the first item to your row, then deleting it from the list? Then next time the button is clicked, add the first item in the list to it's row and then delete it, and so on. If you don't want to delete them, maybe keep an int variable that starts at 0 and add 1 to it each time the button is clicked. Then you just add the item at that position each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over the entire array when you click the button and adding them all back in. Something like this is probably more like what you want:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  if(rowlist.size() > 0)
  {
     table.addView(rowlist.get(0));
     rowlist.remove(0);
  }
}
```